# BusinessObjects 4.1 Upgrade Migration Content

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I have a client needing to move from XI R2 to 4.1.  I need to pick and choose basically 5 thousand reports, and change what folder they will be in.  I will have to actually move the report from one folder to another.  Then the content migration will be easy.  We need to make new folders to account for new AD groups.

How do I get around having to do this manually?  Can I just do it programmatically or in a batch process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create folders and move content using the SDK. In XI r2 you have the choice between the Java, .NET and COM (VB/VBA/VBScript) SDK to perform these actions.

You'll need the *SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise Platform SDK* for this. Here are a few links you might find helpful:

- [SAP BusinessObjects BI 3.x and Lower - Developer SDK Library](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27446)
- [XIr2 JavaDocs](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xir2/boe/en/index.html) ([Zip file](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xir2/boe/en/boesdk_java_apiRef_115_en.zip))
- [.NET API Reference](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/boesdk_net_apiRef_12_en.chm)
- [Object Model Diagrams](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/boesdk_java_omd_12.zip) (Java)
- Developer Guide ([Java](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/boesdk_java_dg_12_en.zip) / [.NET](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/boesdk_net_dg_12_en.chm))
- Sample Code ([Java](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-6220) / [.NET](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-6373))

Where you can find additional information:

- [.NET SDK Application Development](http://scn.sap.com/community/bi-platform/microsoft-net-sdk) forum at SCN
- [Java SDK Application Development](http://scn.sap.com/community/bi-platform/java-sdk) forum at SCN
- [SDK forum](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewforum.php?f=40) at the BusinessObjects Board (unofficial BOBJ forum)

Creating folders and moving content around are quite basic actions, so most of the documentation you'll find (I can only speak for the Java SDK from experience) will largely apply to XI r2, even though it wasn't written for that specific version.